# Best way to set a local printer as default in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, dllimport

I want to set a local printer as default in C#

I have found two ways on Google search:

1. Using IWshRuntimeLibrary and IWshNetwork_Class
2. [DllImport("Winspool.drv")]
   private static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string printerName);

I found #1 in VB on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ed0f29a-a5ff-4328-9c0f-f431f75fccbc/set-defualt-printer?forum=vbgeneral

Its C# Code:

```
new IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshNetwork_Class().SetDefaultPrinter(printerName)
```

So, #1 is a COM interop call. #2 is a straightforward dll call.

I have tried both and both work fine. So, which on should I use? Do I need to install a separate library (on client's machine) for #1 ?

Comment: I have defined dllimport, just under class without try and catch. So, in case of exception, can I catch it in catch{} when calling the defined function in code, if the called function of dllimport fails for some reason? or the whole program will crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose the direct DLL call.  I would bet that `IWshRuntimeLibrary` calls `Winspool.drv` internally, and you take the COM layer out of the picture.  It seems unlikely that a windows machine would not have Windows Scripting Host registered properly, but it seems even less likely that `Winspool.drv` is not available.

Comment: I have defined dllimport, just under class without try and catch. So, in case of exception, can I catch it in catch{} when calling the defined function in code, if the called function of dllimport fails for some reason? or the whole program will crash?

Comment: You can't wrap attributes in a try/catch, but if the DLL is missing, you will get a `DllNotFoundException` when _calling_ the function.  Be aware that some unmanaged exceptions cannot be caught by the .NET runtime and will likely abort the process.

Answer (score 1):

I think .NET has what you are looking for in the form of a managed solution. Try checking out the [LocalPrintServer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing.LocalPrintServer%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specifically the [DefaultPrintQueue property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.localprintserver.defaultprintqueue%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And here is some [example code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/052a0085-f1fe-4b9d-8907-1a360857de17/setting-a-local-default-printer-using-localprintserverdefaultprintqueue-property)